# Can not bind Radio button with angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 RC7.

My radio buttons are not bound, but why?

I get no error message at all.

```
<input name="options" [value]="true"  [(ngModel)]="gradingKey.halfScoresCount" type="radio" />
<input name="options" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="gradingKey.halfScoresCount" type="radio" />

export class EditGradingKey {

  halfScoresCount: string;
  constructor(obj:any) {  
    this.halfScoresCount = "true"; //obj.halfScoresCount;  
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `gradingKey` in `gradingKey.halfScoresCount`?

Comment: gradingKey is a class instance with property halfScoresCount. Other properties bound to gradingKey instance properties work fine, that is not the cause ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like in this plunkr I found: http://plnkr.co/edit/pRPwDKP9wpp7hOlOgBbx?p=preview

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Half scores count?</label>
    <div style="display:inline-block;" *ngFor="let answer of gradingKey.halfScoresCountAnswers">
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" [(ngModel)]="gradingKey.currentAnswer" [value]="answer.value">{{answer.display}}</label>
    </div>
</div>

export class EditGradingKey {

genders: any[];
currentAnswer: any;

constructor(obj: any) {
this.genders = [ { value: 'true', display: 'Yes I want' },{ value: 'false', display: 'No I don`t' } ];
this.currentAnswer= obj.halfScoresCount == true ? this.genders[0].value : this.genders[1].value;

}
}
```